# My firebase writes & reads are exploding without any indications, any ideas?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app has stopped working and my console is giving errors stating that I've reached my quota. I have checked my dashboard on firebase and seen that in the last couple of days (without explanation) my reads and writes have exploded. No more users, no more content.

Below is a one day difference between normal expected behaviour and a complete overload.

Before:
[image: Before]

After: [image: After]

Any ideas?

I tried reviewing my code but I haven't made any changes that would affect the database...

Most likely culprit:

```
class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    @Published var stories = [Story]()

    let service = PostService()
    let userService = UserService()
    
    init() {
        fetchPosts()
        fetchStories()
    }
    
    func fetchPosts() {
        service.fetchPosts { posts in
            self.posts = posts
            
            for i in 0 ..< posts.count {
                let uid = posts[i].uid
                
                self.userService.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { user in
                    self.posts[i].user = user
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    func fetchStories() {
        service.fetchStories { stories in
            self.stories = stories
            
            for i in 0 ..< stories.count {
                let uid = stories[i].uid
                
                self.userService.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { user in
                    self.stories[i].user = user
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I added a print statement and it was sent to the console 40 or so times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are those writes? Can you go in the database and see what new items are being added?

Comment: In the meantime I would use `firebase hosting:disable` to disable the site until you figure it out because it could cost you quite a bit.

Comment: Show us the code the produces those reads and writes.

Comment: @JonasGrumann How exactly would I check exactly whats reading & being written? Is there an audit log or history log or something?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've attached my most likely culprit, it seems like this code is being run multiple times when I added a print statement to the original function.

Comment: That's most likely happening because you're performing those operations in a loop, right?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue since your code only reads the db but the screenshot shows it's actually writing something

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I use a for each loop.

Comment: True @JonasGrumann

Comment: Unless I am missing something (quite possible) the code in the question does not write anything (as previously mentioned) so it would be unrelated to 'exploding' writes. You should include the code in the question that actually writes data. Do you have any server functions? Are you doing anything in the Firebase Console? Also, the title states 'and reads' but there's no indication of 'exploding' reads in the question. Can you clarify?